# secure a php file that contains ajax functions called by jQuery?

Tags: php, ajax, security, authentication

I have a php file that contains ajax functions.
This file requires no authentication, it is placed in the folder

```
('config/ajax.php')
```

I need to secure it, to disalow query it for all the data that the functions return.
Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Everything that is callable from AJAX will be public and you can't prevent anyone from calling it. Could you provide more details about what you are trying to achieve (preferably with some example code).

Comment: If you want people to be able to use a page that calls these ajax functions, but you don't want people to see all the data that the ajax functions return, then you need to rethink your architecture.

Comment: You cannot let the client query your data without letting clients query your data, unless you use authentication to distinguish attackers from legitimate users.

Answer (score 0):

Write a query that doesn't return all the data?

Do you have an example of the code you can provide?  Are you including this in a php file?

Ideally you will pass in a parameter to the ajax function you are calling, if no parameter is passed in, it won't return any data.  Not return all the data.

Please post your examples so we can help more.

Comment: the ajax.php file is placed on the folder config with other files like : config.php, db.php....

in this file i have a switch/case statement to define which function to execute, exp :

    <?php
    header("Content-type: text/json");
    require_once ('config.php');
    require_once ('db.php'); 
    require_once ('fcts.php');

    switch ($_POST['fnct_name']) {
    case "fct1":
    echo fct1_json();
    break;
    case "fct2":
    echo fct2_json();
    break;
    }
....

Answer (score 0):

You can do some validation to ajax request, like Okmer said all ajax will be public.

But you can pass some param to garantee that ajax was called by your application...

Like

```
ajax.php?auth=2134
```

And

```
$auth = $_POST['auth'];
if($auth == 'somecode')
//ok can response.
```

Comment: And then an attacker can pass the same parameter.

Comment: So you should think a way to make this param unique and only valid if generated my application @SLaks

Comment: If atacker have the right info he can atack all sytem on the world. This is the main security issue, save you vital aspects from the system to prevent atacks.

Comment: But the attacker can read the value of the parameter from your app.  You need a shared secret.

Comment: But if each situation generate a param you can do that. Like, servertime ddmmyyyy+userid+some kind of unique key, and each time change this can. Can be done without problem.

Comment: No.  Unless you have some kind of shared secret, you can't prevent the attacker's client from getting the same info that your client has.

Comment: Let say, you have some random generated number on session to that user, and this number have 1 use validate, the ideia is prevent other ppl access the ajax service from out of application. So, when the user get the html the application get this random number and put it on HTML, to futute use on ajax. When this number get use the application will generate other number or something. The attacker's can get the first number, but until it get used it isn't valid more. I have sure has many was to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're passing an actual query to the .php file rather than a parameter like an id etc, then what's the problem with them accessing the same results differently?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem today, what I am doing is, I have self made a function which encrypt a string, then I decrypt on ajax page to get back value, I used to matched them there like this.

```
class MyEncryption
{

public $pubkey  = 789584875986;
private $privkey = 878458785986;

public function encrypt($key)
  {
   $encript = $key+$this->privkey;
   return $key = 7*$encript;

  }

public function decrypt($key)
  {
    $d = $key/7;
    return $descript = $d-$this->privkey;
  }
}
```